Multivariate Probit Model gives warnings in R
I have a set of agricultural practice adoption data for a set of plots, and demographics and other survey variables associated with each farmer.
Some points to note - a few farmers have multiple plots listed, so practice information varies while demographic data stays the same.
I am trying to use 2 main types of analysis. The first is a Random Forest approach where I ran a classification RF for each of the agricultural practices and looked at the permutation importances to see which were the most important explanatory variables. My OOB errors are not great - 36%, 14% and 21%.
The second approach was one I found based on literature - a multivariate probit model as seen in Kassie et al 2009: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1111/j.1477-8947.2009.01224.x (sorry I think it is not open access!).
I removed any highly correlated variables, made all my categorical variables into dummy variables and used the mvProbit package to run the analysis.
An example:
df <- tibble(AgPrac = c(1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1), 
             AgPrac2 = c(1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1),
             AgPrac3 = c(1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0),
             Farmer_Woman = c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1), 
             District2 = c(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1),
             Farmer_age = c(41, 31, 61, 39, 50, 54, 60,55),
             Farmer_educ_primary = c(0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1),
             Farmer_educ_secondary = c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))

prob_mod <- mvProbit(cbind(AgPrac, AgPrac2, AgPrac3) ~ Farmer_Woman + District2 + Farmer_age +     Farmer_educ_primary + Farmer_educ_secondary, data = df) `

I have about 9 such regular + dummy variables and would like to add more, and have around 1100 plot observations.
As seen in this Posit forum question, I get many (50 +) warnings that the correlation matrix is not positive definite. I tried removing variables from the model but it did not help. I do not think I have a dummy variable trap. Could anyone explain why I am getting this error and how to address it? Should I just stick to running 3 univariate probit models? Does this have something to do with repeated farmer demographics for some plots -- should I select the plots with maximum adoption and keep only unique farmer IDs?
I am not supposed to share the actual data but can provide any other information...

or just compute the correlation matrix yourself and inspect that, or look at its eigenvalues -- non-pd correlation matrix implies at least one eigenvalue is zero -- and then look at the associated eigenvectors. My pretty strong recommendation is to steer away from random forests or other ML models because you need to be able to interpret the model and make inferences from it, and for that purpose conventional models are much more suitable.

From your example code I did not any warnings about non positive definite correlation matrix. But you should check this for your full data. You can also look at variance inflation factors of the predictor matrix to see if the variables are linearly dependent
